# Можно ли использовать absolute в верстке письма?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, табличная-верстка

Есть ли варианты использовать абсолют, ну и соответственно right, left, top, bottom? У меня задача встала, нужно на огромную картинку наложить ссылки и их расставить по местам. Есть варианты? Вообще хоть как то можно использовать CSS в вёрстке письма?

Comment: Css использовать так же, как для верстки обычного сайта.. Либо в head, либо style атрибут у эл-тов

Answer (score 2):

Если вы готовите HTML-документ для почтовой рассылки, то CSS отдельным файлом выносить не получится. Многие почтовые программы обрезают все внешние CSS файлы и медиа-запросы. В данном случае для определения стиля элементов письма с помощью правил CSS применяется атрибут `style`. Вот его синтаксис:

```
<тег style="правила описания стилей"></тег>
```

В качестве значений указываются обычные стилевые правила. Вначале имя стилевого свойства, а затем через двоеточие его значение. Стилевые свойства разделяются между собой точкой с запятой. Атрибут `style` применяется к различным тегам.

Это была небольшая теория. Теперь вернемся непосредственно к вашему вопросу:

> У меня задача встала, нужно на огромную картинку наложить ссылки и их
> расставить по местам.

Приведу вам простой пример, где показано, каким образом можно решить вашу задачу:

```html
<div style="position: relative; width: 500px; height: 300px;
background: url(https://i.imgur.com/Joed5du.jpg);
background-position: bottom right;">
<a href="#" style="position: absolute; top: 60px; left: 50px;">Ссылка 1</a>
<a href="#" style="position: absolute; bottom: 50px; left: 85px;">Ссылка 2</a>
<a href="#" style="position: absolute; top: 85px; right: 80px;">Ссылка 3</a>
</div>
```

Однако, при всём этом нужно ещё учитывать, что некоторые почтовые клиенты в целях безопасности могут вырезать часть HTML-кода письма. Кроме этого, и каждый провайдер может по-разному реагировать на одно и то же свойство.

---

**upd.** Добавил пример, в случае, если у вас табличная вёрстка. Хотя, исходя из моего уже многолетнего опыта по email-рассылкам, могу утверждать, что абсолютно никакой разницы нет, какая будет вёрстка.

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;
position: relative; width: 500px; height: 300px;
background: url(https://i.imgur.com/Joed5du.jpg);
background-position: bottom right;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
<a href="#" style="position: absolute; top: 60px; left: 50px;">Ссылка 1</a>
<a href="#" style="position: absolute; bottom: 50px; left: 85px;">Ссылка 2</a>
<a href="#" style="position: absolute; top: 85px; right: 80px;">Ссылка 3</a>
      </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Письма вроде через table делают

Comment: Минус исправил..

Comment: я сам пробовал отсылать с php письма с div - не канало, как вставляю table всё тип топ ... я не спорю

Comment: @Sevastopol' , а если все стили внутри тега ```<style></style>``` прописывать, будет работать? У вас в ответе везде именно в атрибутах style стили написаны

Comment: @Sevastopol' а жаль, в атрибутах конечно же меньше удобства с точки зрения управления стилей. Спасибо за ответ)